# Ruby 1.9.1 is not working under rvm, mac os x

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, rvm, ruby-1.9.1

I had rvm installed for several months and it has system (1.8.7) and installed (1.9.1) rubies listed. And both versions worked fine. Yesterday I tried to update 1.9.1 but after installation it wasn't working and system ruby gone from rvm list. I removed rvm, made clean install of rvm. But when I'm installing 1.9.1 via rvm it says:

```
info: Installation of ruby-1.9.1-p378 is complete.

info: Updating rubygems for /Users/nimf/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378@global

error: Error running '/Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/gem update --system', please check /Users/nimf/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.1-p378/rubygems.update*.log

info: Updating rubygems for /Users/nimf/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378

error: Error running '/Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/gem update --system', please check /Users/nimf/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.1-p378/rubygems.update*.log
```

In these log files:

```
[2010-08-17 09:17:31] /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/gem update --system
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/libruby.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/ruby
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ruby requires version 1.9.1 or later, but libruby.dylib provides version 1.8.0
/Users/nimf/.rvm/scripts/utility: line 180: 81885 Trace/BPT trap          /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/gem update --system
[2010-08-17 09:17:32] /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/gem update --system
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/libruby.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/ruby
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ruby requires version 1.9.1 or later, but libruby.dylib provides version 1.8.0
/Users/nimf/.rvm/scripts/utility: line 180: 81907 Trace/BPT trap          /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/gem update --system
```

And nor ruby, nor gems or irb working, giving same error:

```
$ ruby
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/libruby.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/ruby
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ruby requires version 1.9.1 or later, but libruby.dylib provides version 1.8.0
Trace/BPT trap
$ gem list
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/libruby.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/ruby
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ruby requires version 1.9.1 or later, but libruby.dylib provides version 1.8.0
Trace/BPT trap
```

ls -la /Users/nimf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/ gives:

```
total 17232
drwxr-xr-x  7 nimf  staff      238 17 авг 09:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 nimf  staff      238 17 авг 09:17 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 nimf  staff  6617504 17 авг 09:13 libruby-static.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nimf  staff  2193720 17 авг 09:13 libruby.1.9.1.dylib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 nimf  staff       19 17 авг 09:16 libruby.1.9.dylib -> libruby.1.9.1.dylib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 nimf  staff       19 17 авг 09:16 libruby.dylib -> libruby.1.9.1.dylib
drwxr-xr-x  6 nimf  staff      204 17 авг 09:17 ruby
```

I've also installed 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 under rvm and they work perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

The previous post from AboutRuby should be updated, since it is an old version

```
$ rvm get head
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of RVM are you using?  It's often useful to upgrade to RVM HEAD before trying to install any rubies.  You can do this as described [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/Upgrading-To-Rvm-Head.--qS.htm), or as so:

```
$ rvm update --head
```

This might not fix the problem, but newer versions of RVM straight from git often include little workarounds to get rubies working on various platforms.